# How to fix my nested structure issue?

Tags: c

I am writing a program that has to read from a delimited file and then print the output. The delimiter is a pound sign '#' . Right now I keep getting the error " field not found: buildingType". I know this is because of my nested structure but for my program i was told that its how its supposed to be written. My return type for my parseListing() method needs to be void which is why I think I might be coming up with errors also. I need to find away to fix this without changing my return type from void. Also in my delimited file, there are some values that are listed as "N/A" and I need those not to show up when I print the characters from the file. My delimited file looks like this except with no spaces in between each line(I put spaces into the text box for formatting purposes on this site).

---

Here is my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char buildingType[10];
    int numBedrooms;
    int numBathrooms;
    }Propertylisting;

typedef struct {

Propertylisting propertylisting;
    char address[100];
    char unitNum [10];
    char city [50];





void printPropertyListing(Listing l) {
    printf("%s %s %s\n%s %d %d %d\n\n", l.address, l.unitNum, l.city, l.buildingType, l.numBedrooms, l.numBathrooms, l.listPrice);
}
```

Comment: What's the line `char delimiter['#'];` supposed to do? This way you are defining an array of 35 chars without assigning any values.

Comment: @halex the char delimiter ['#']; is suposed to be used as the delimiter field the program is supposed to use to seperate the values. or so i thought. lol.

Comment: `void parseListings(...` : return type `void`.

Comment: Ah ok :). `delimiter` has to be a C string containing all delimiters, in your case only `#`. Do `char *delimiter = "#";` (note the use of `"` instead of `'` to get a null terminated string instead of just the plain char)

Comment: @halex thanks. Hope that works. I cant test it right now because of the other errors im getting. lol. thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your `PropertyListing` is a field in your `Listing` structure. You're trying to assign to `listing[n].buildingType`, which doesn't exist in your `Listing` structure.

They do exist in your `PropertyListing` structure however, of which one is included in your `Listing` structure under the name `propertyListing`. You can simply access `propertyListing` as a standard structure field, then access the members of `PropertyListing` through that member. As an example, see the following code:

```
listing[n].propertyListing.buildingType; // For the building type string
listing[n].propertyListing.numBedrooms;  // For the number of bedrooms
```

And so on.

Comment: that seemed to solve the buildingType problem, but now a couple lines down its giving me another error saying  'numBedrooms' undeclared. do you know why its giving me this?

Comment: @user3672889, `numBedrooms` is again part of the inner structure, so you need to do the same technique to access it. Also, the other `numBedrooms` definition doesn't exist. You *do* define a field called `length` above it though, which may be what you wantt?

Comment: thanks you @slugonamission. Stupid mistake on my part, i forgot to change those variables. everything in that method seems to work now. I have one more problem though. At the bottom you will see my printPropertyListing() method. in that line it is giving me an error saying  "field not found: buildingType" I assume its because of what you were telling me before, how its not a field inside listing. im not sure how to fix this. running through the 3 variables before it with no errors. its just that one building type variable its giving me an error for. the next 2 probably aswell Any suggestions?

Comment: I got it to work, I just put l.propertylisting.buildingtype LOL. thanks again. unfortunatly now my program just crashes when i run it in the prompt :(